# Symlink to /Documents /Pictures etc. in OS X Home Directory?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd

I have just purchased a 120GB SSD with the intent of making it my boot drive. I'd like to keep it as lean as possible since, y'know, it's so small (Heaven help me). I've read [Can I move my home folder in Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/25128/can-i-move-my-home-folder-in-mac-os-x) and [Moving Mac OS X user folders?](https://superuser.com/questions/25083/moving-mac-os-x-user-folders) which discourage moving the entire home dir to a data drive. Is it possible and less-dangerous to leave the home directory on the boot drive but move the big data directories to a slower drive and symlink to them?

I have the same thoughts with the /Applications directory, but maybe I should make that a separate question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Things like a large music library probably do you more good being on a big spinning disk.  But you don't need to symlink them.  You can tell iTunes to open a library other than the one in the default location, just hold Alt when launching it.

For Pictures, you can do the same thing (iPhoto supports the same Alt key trick when launching).

Most other applications either don't care or will let you change the location of their default storage paths.  Those that do not, you can most likely use Symlinks without any ill effects, but YMMV.

I would hesitate putting Applications there, since you gain a lot of performance by having them live on the SSD.